# devise_scope not finding mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using `devise_scope` to define my routes, so as to shorten the list of generated routes that I do not use.

I have this routes file:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'Identity::User', skip: :all

        namespace :users do
          devise_scope :user do
            post 'sign_in', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :create
            delete 'sign_out', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :destroy
            post '/', controller: "/api/v1/identity/registrations", action: :create
          end
```

I have confirmed this generates the routes as expected. When the sign_in route is hit, it does appear to hit the proper controller, `SessionController`, which extends `Devise::SessionsController`. However, I get the below error:

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/api/v1/users/sign_in".
This may happen for two reasons:

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]


Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I assume that somehow the devise_for is not properly setting up the routes I need?

EDIT: Solution, but not ideal.

The issue in my case, was the devise_for was not mapping properly. The full routes included another namespace that I neglected to paste:

```
namespace :api do
devise_for :users, class_name: 'Identity::User', skip: :all

namespace :users do
  devise_scope :user do
    post 'sign_in', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :create
    delete 'sign_out', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :destroy
    post '/', controller: "/api/v1/identity/registrations", action: :create
  end
end
end
```

However, if I move devise for outside of the api namespace, the mappings are correct:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'Identity::User', skip: :all

namespace :api do

namespace :users do
  devise_scope :user do
    post 'sign_in', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :create
    delete 'sign_out', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :destroy
    post '/', controller: "/api/v1/identity/registrations", action: :create
  end
end
end
```

I use nested routes files, so doing this breaks my structure. Is there a way to adjust this to work with it inside of that api namespace?

Answer (score 1):

so basically I believe that devies is trying to use the "devise" controllers while being namespaced.

So when inside the `:api` namespace rails looks for `Api::Devise::Sessions` (or something similar) controller while devise expects just `Devise::Sessions`

what to do in this case?

1. try `devise_for :users, class_name: 'Identity::User', path: :api, skip: :all`
2. you can try using `scope :api do` instead of `namespace :api do`

   this affects the created paths but rails still should be looking for correct devise controller
3. explicitly tell devise which controller to use

and idea of how exactly point 3 can look like:

```
namespace :api do
  devise_for :users, class_name: 'Identity::User', controllers: { session: "api/v1/sessions" }, skip: :all    
  namespace :users do
    devise_scope :user do
      post 'sign_in', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :create
      delete 'sign_out', controller: "/api/v1/identity/sessions", action: :destroy
      post '/', controller: "/api/v1/identity/registrations", action: :create
    end
  end
end
```